# Data Migration From Multilevel XML to Single Table With SSIS

Tags: sql-server, xml, ssis, database-migration

**Goal**

I am attempting to migrate data from a multi-layered XML file with nested elements to a single table.

**System Parameters**

- MS SQL Server Management Studio
- Microsoft Visual Studio SSIS

**The XML File**

[Here's the XSD for the XML file I have](http://pastebin.com/gS1xwJf1)

As you can see, it is not just a simple layout. The whole thing is wrapped in a 'People' tag, and there about ~1000 'Person's. Each 'Person' tag contains the following elements of information. The XML goes like this:

Person

- FirstName
- LastName
- Biography
- Expertise
- Image
- Link
- Books

  - Book

    - Year
    - Details
  - Book

    - Year
    - Details
  - ... (There can be many of these)
- Articles

  - Article

    - Year
    - Details
  - Article

    - Year
    - Details
  - ... (There can be many of these)
- Papers
- Artwork
- Websites

As a side note, there can be multiple

**Question**

Now, here's my question. How do I put all of this information into a **single** SQL table with SSIS? I know that the topology of the XML file doesn't directly map onto the topology of a table, but I want to force it. I want a separate row for each 'Person'. I also want enough columns to capture the maximum number of 'Book's that any one person in my data set has. Maybe this means creating 'Book_1', 'Book_2', 'Book_3'.. etc. columns in the final table. I *do not* want a series of tables with foreign and primary keys. I want a separate column for each 'Book', 'Year' 'Details' corresponding to each element. To be more clear, let me show you want I mean with an example.

**Example XML File**

If I have a 'Books' tag with 3 'Book' elements, I want to create a separate column for each book:

- John
- Steinbeck
- ...
- Books

  - East of Eden

    - 1952
    - A great book
  - Of Mice And Men

    - 1937
    - Book about mice
  - The Grapes of Wrath

    - 1939
    - Book about angry grapes
- Articles

  - Article
- ...

**Example Resulting Table In SQL Database**

I want the table to look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7aM2u.png), and look like this for all of the nested elements of the XML file. Is it possible to do a kind of flattened import to a database in this manner using SSIS?

Thanks! I really appreciate it.

**Additional Notes**

- Some of the entries in the XML file contain up to 60,000 characters. What data type does that mean I should use?

**Snippet of Actual XML File**

Here's an example of the XML file. The actual XML has many `<Person>`'s.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<People>
    <Person>
        <FirstName>Eliza</FirstName>
        <LastName>Ablovatski</LastName>
        <Biography>
            <![CDATA[<p>Eliza Ablovatski joined the Kenyon history department in 2003, after graduate work in East Central European history at Columbia University and research and fellowships in Munich and Berlin, Germany and Budapest, Hungary. She teaches classes on Europe from 1500 to the present, focusing on the nineteenth and twentieth centuries, Germany, Russia, the Habsburg Monarchy, film, nationalism and identity, gender, race, and the interwar period.</p>
<p>Her dissertation and first book,&nbsp;<em>Revolution and Political Violence in Central Europe: The Deluge of 1919</em> (forthcoming from Cambridge University Press), focus on the revolutionary upheavals in Munich and Budapest following the First World War, and their relationship to political violence and antisemitism. She is currently researching the occupation of Austria (1945-1955) at the end of the Second World War, and the nuclear idea in postwar Europe. She has also researched and written extensively on the history of Jews in the former Habsburg regional capital of Czernowitz (now Ukraine).</p>]]>
        </Biography>
        <Expertise>
            <![CDATA[<p>Modern Europe, especially Germany and Central/East Central Europe in the nineteenth and twentieth centuries; European Jewish and women's history, East European and German film and literature, socialism, war, and revolution.</p>]]>
        </Expertise>
        <Image>http://www.kenyon.edu/images/directory/ablovatski.jpg</Image>
        <Link>http://www.kenyon.edu/directories/campus-directory/biography/eliza-ablovatski/</Link>
        <Books>
            <Book>
                <Year></Year>
                <Details>
                    <![CDATA[<p><em>Zwischen Pruth und Jordan. Lebenserinnerungen Czernowitzer Juden</em><em>&nbsp;,&nbsp;</em>with Gaby Coldewey and others K&ouml;ln: B&ouml;hlau Verlag, 2003</p>]]>
                </Details>
            </Book>
            <Book>
                <Year></Year>
                <Details>
                    <![CDATA[<p><em>Czernowitz ist gewen an alt jiddische Stdt: &Uuml;berlebende berichten,</em>&nbsp;With Gaby Coldewey and others. First Edition: Czernowitz,Ukraine: distributed by the Heinrich-B&ouml;ll-Stiftung, 1998 Second Edition: Berlin, 1999 (Third edition: Potsdam, forthcoming 2009)</p>]]>
                </Details>
            </Book>
        </Books>
        <Articles>
            <Article>
                <Year></Year>
                <Details>
                    <![CDATA[<p>"The Central European Revolutions of 1919 and the Myth of Judeo-Bolshevism,"&nbsp;<em>European Review of History, Vol. 17/ Issue 3: Cosmopolitanism, Nationalism and the Jews of East Central Europe (2010), 473-489.</em></p>]]>
                </Details>
            </Article>
            <Article>
                <Year></Year>
                <Details>
                    <![CDATA[<p>"Between Red Army and White Guard: Women in Budapest, 1918-1919," in&nbsp;<em>Gender and War in Twentieth-Century Eastern Europe,</em>&nbsp;edited by Maria Bucur and Nancy Wingfield&nbsp;Bloomington: Indiana University Press 2006</p>]]>
                </Details>
            </Article>
            <Article>
                <Year></Year>
                <Details>
                    <![CDATA[<p>"The Girl with the Titus-head: Women in Revolution in Munich and Budapest, 1919"&nbsp;<em>Nationalities Papers&nbsp;</em>28/3 (September 2000), 541-550</p>]]>
                </Details>
            </Article>
        </Articles>
        <Papers>
        </Papers>
        <Artwork>
        </Artwork>
        <Websites>
        </Websites>
    </Person>
...This goes on to include many <Person> elements. (About 1000)
</People>
```

Comment: Please poste one real example of your XML. The schema doesn't help so much...

Comment: Alright! I added a snippet of the XML file that I want to import into my SQL database.

Comment: Hi, I just added a dynamic SQL approach...

Comment: I see! Does it result in only one table, or multiple with relational foreign and primary keys?

Comment: The related tables are just an intermediate step. The final result will be the *one big table*

Comment: I got the first query working with the toy XML file. I however did not get the second part to work.. I get this error. 

`Msg 2714, Level 16, State 1, Line 191
There is already an object named '#tempAllData' in the database.`

Comment: At the very end there are several `DROP TABLE` statements. The `SELECT col1,col2, .... INTO #tempTable` tries to **create** a table and fails if this exists already. If everything is fine, the final statements are executed, if you get an error in between, the aren't. You might set a line break and a `GO` before each of them. This way they should be hit in any case...

Comment: First, I hope it's OK that concatenate the queries, and do them together rather than separately in two different queries. Second, I wanted to show you what I added to the end of the big query..
`PIVOT
(
    MAX(Data) FOR ColumnName IN(' +  @columnNames + ')
) AS p;'


EXEC(@cmd);
GO
DROP TABLE #tempArticles
GO
DROP TABLE #tempBooks
GO 

DROP TABLE #tempPerson
GO

DROP TABLE #tempAllData;
GO
`
I still get the error: http://imgur.com/KEvUqgQ

Comment: The second code box (starting with `WITH MyPersonCTE ...` down to `... DROP TABLE #tempAllData;` should be use in one piece. Just take the declaration of the test XML from the first box (starting with `DECLARE @x ...` down to `</People>';`) and copy this **before** the query code. Then execute this. Works here...

Comment: Alright! I get a result. However, it has these parentheses-wrapped bits before each of the entries in the table. Is this intentional? How do I get rid of these? Will these show up when I pull from the table? Thanks. Here's what I'm talking about: http://imgur.com/FrASSNJ

Comment: I am also having trouble with the ' in women's. How do I escape all of these?

Comment: Firstly: The paratheses are on purpose. It is - without tricks - not possible to pivot more than one column. So I concatenate the year and the details here `,''(Year '' + CAST(BookYear AS VARCHAR(4)) + '') '' + BookDetails AS Data` You can change this however you like... Secondly: Just use a `REPLACE(YourXMLasVARCHAR,'''','''''')` to double all contained quotes.

Comment: Alright, will do. How would I change this if I do not want t parenthetical appendages?

Comment: Something like this: `,'' + ISULL(CAST(ArticleYear AS VARCHAR(4)),'''') + '' '' + ArticleDetails`

Comment: How do I set the XML equal to a VARCHAR variable?

Comment: I just edited my answer. Re-Copy the second code block. The years will be without paranthesis (or missing if not set)

Comment: How is the XML coming into your code? If it is XML already you don't have to bother about `women's`. If you get it as varchar somehow you should do the replace **before** you cast it to XML. The problem with `women's ` should **only** appear if you copy the XML string manually into a query window. Use the built in REPLACE (strg+h) to set all quotes to double quotes.

Comment: Thank you! Now I'm having issues when I try to copy and paste the large XML file in place of the toy XML file that I was using before. it says there are illegal characters... `Msg 9420, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
XML parsing: line 1132, character 265, illegal xml character` The XML file I'm using is here: https://drive.google.com/a/kenyon.edu/file/d/0B-kqwqzOZXDYWnRtXzUzbXFDbVE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I did the replace in sublime text 2, and then just copied and pasted it into the place where you had the toy xml in single quotes. It worked, but now I'm getting this other issue above about illegal xml characters

Comment: This is becoming a [Chameleon Question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions). Anyway, this should not be handled in so many comments. No future reader will ever read this lot... If my answer solves **this** question please tick the acceptance check (below the vote counter). And than start a new question. Place a link here and I'll pop up there soon.

Comment: OK! Great Sounds good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thx for the actual XML! The following query will get your values out of the XML. It will generate IDs for them to store all data in related tables.

Attention: I had to double the `'` sign in `woman's` and I added a second `person` to show the approach:

```SQL
DECLARE @x XML=
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<People>
    <Person>
        <FirstName>Eliza</FirstName>
        <LastName>Ablovatski</LastName>
        <Biography>
            <![CDATA[<p>Eliza Ablovatski joined the Kenyon history department in 2003, after graduate work in East Central European history at Columbia University and research and fellowships in Munich and Berlin, Germany and Budapest, Hungary. She teaches classes on Europe from 1500 to the present, focusing on the nineteenth and twentieth centuries, Germany, Russia, the Habsburg Monarchy, film, nationalism and identity, gender, race, and the interwar period.</p>
<p>Her dissertation and first book,&nbsp;<em>Revolution and Political Violence in Central Europe: The Deluge of 1919</em> (forthcoming from Cambridge University Press), focus on the revolutionary upheavals in Munich and Budapest following the First World War, and their relationship to political violence and antisemitism. She is currently researching the occupation of Austria (1945-1955) at the end of the Second World War, and the nuclear idea in postwar Europe. She has also researched and written extensively on the history of Jews in the former Habsburg regional capital of Czernowitz (now Ukraine).</p>]]>
        </Biography>
        <Expertise>
            <![CDATA[<p>Modern Europe, especially Germany and Central/East Central Europe in the nineteenth and twentieth centuries; European Jewish and women''s history, East European and German film and literature, socialism, war, and revolution.</p>]]>
        </Expertise>
        <Image>http://www.kenyon.edu/images/directory/ablovatski.jpg</Image>
        <Link>http://www.kenyon.edu/directories/campus-directory/biography/eliza-ablovatski/</Link>
        <Books>
            <Book>
                <Year></Year>
                <Details>
                    <![CDATA[<p><em>Zwischen Pruth und Jordan. Lebenserinnerungen Czernowitzer Juden</em><em>&nbsp;,&nbsp;</em>with Gaby Coldewey and others K&ouml;ln: B&ouml;hlau Verlag, 2003</p>]]>
                </Details>
            </Book>
            <Book>
                <Year></Year>
                <Details>
                    <![CDATA[<p><em>Czernowitz ist gewen an alt jiddische Stdt: &Uuml;berlebende berichten,</em>&nbsp;With Gaby Coldewey and others. First Edition: Czernowitz,Ukraine: distributed by the Heinrich-B&ouml;ll-Stiftung, 1998 Second Edition: Berlin, 1999 (Third edition: Potsdam, forthcoming 2009)</p>]]>
                </Details>
            </Book>
        </Books>
        <Articles>
            <Article>
                <Year></Year>
                <Details>
                    <![CDATA[<p>"The Central European Revolutions of 1919 and the Myth of Judeo-Bolshevism,"&nbsp;<em>European Review of History, Vol. 17/ Issue 3: Cosmopolitanism, Nationalism and the Jews of East Central Europe (2010), 473-489.</em></p>]]>
                </Details>
            </Article>
            <Article>
                <Year></Year>
                <Details>
                    <![CDATA[<p>"Between Red Army and White Guard: Women in Budapest, 1918-1919," in&nbsp;<em>Gender and War in Twentieth-Century Eastern Europe,</em>&nbsp;edited by Maria Bucur and Nancy Wingfield&nbsp;Bloomington: Indiana University Press 2006</p>]]>
                </Details>
            </Article>
            <Article>
                <Year></Year>
                <Details>
                    <![CDATA[<p>"The Girl with the Titus-head: Women in Revolution in Munich and Budapest, 1919"&nbsp;<em>Nationalities Papers&nbsp;</em>28/3 (September 2000), 541-550</p>]]>
                </Details>
            </Article>
        </Articles>
        <Papers>
        </Papers>
        <Artwork>
        </Artwork>
        <Websites>
        </Websites>
    </Person>
    <Person>
        <FirstName>One</FirstName>
        <LastName>More</LastName>
        <Biography>Biography: Some interesting facts...</Biography>
        <Expertise>Expertise: Some interesting facts...</Expertise>
        <Image>somepicture.jpg</Image>
        <Link>somelink.com</Link>
        <Books>
            <Book>
                <Year>2001</Year>
                <Details>Book1</Details>
            </Book>
            <Book>
                <Year>2002</Year>
                <Details>Book2</Details>
            </Book>
        </Books>
        <Articles>
            <Article>
                <Year>2001</Year>
                <Details>Article1</Details>
            </Article>
        </Articles>
        <Papers>
        </Papers>
        <Artwork>
        </Artwork>
        <Websites>
        </Websites>
    </Person>
</People>';

With MyPersonCTE AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS PersonID
          ,p.value('FirstName[1]','varchar(max)') AS FirstName
          ,p.value('LastName[1]','varchar(max)') AS LastName
          ,p.value('Biography[1]','varchar(max)') AS Biography
          ,p.value('Expertise[1]','varchar(max)') AS Expertise
          ,p.value('Image[1]','varchar(max)') AS Image
          ,p.value('Link[1]','varchar(max)') AS Link
          ,p.query('Books') AS BookNode
          ,p.query('Articles') AS ArticleNode
          --same for Papers, Artwork...
    FROM @x.nodes('/People/Person') AS A(p) 
)
,MyBooksCTE AS
(
    SELECT MyPersonCTE.*
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS BookID
          ,x.value('Year[1]','int') AS BookYear
          ,x.value('Details[1]','varchar(max)') AS BookDetails
    FROM MyPersonCTE
    CROSS APPLY MyPersonCTE.BookNode.nodes('/Books/Book') A(x)  
)
,MyArticlesCTE AS
(
    SELECT MyPersonCTE.*
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS ArticleID
          ,x.value('Year[1]','int') AS ArticleYear
          ,x.value('Details[1]','varchar(max)') AS ArticleDetails
    FROM MyPersonCTE
    CROSS APPLY MyPersonCTE.ArticleNode.nodes('/Articles/Article') A(x)  
)
--same for Papers, Artwork...
SELECT p.*
      ,b.BookID
      ,b.BookYear
      ,b.BookDetails
      ,a.ArticleID
      ,a.ArticleYear
      ,a.ArticleDetails  
INTO #tempAllData
FROM MyPersonCTE AS p
LEFT JOIN MyBooksCTE AS b ON p.PersonID=b.PersonID
LEFT JOIN MyArticlesCTE AS a ON p.PersonID=a.PersonID ;

--#tempAllData is now filled with all data, copied in all combination: much to much
--but DISTINCT is your friend
--in this case you'd use the PersonID as FK in all related tables

SELECT DISTINCT PersonID,FirstName,LastName,Biography,Expertise --other fields
FROM #tempAllData;

SELECT DISTINCT PersonID,BookID,BookYear,BookDetails
FROM #tempAllData;

SELECT DISTINCT PersonID,ArticleID,ArticleYear,ArticleDetails
FROM #tempAllData;

DROP TABLE #tempAllData;
```

#### The results

Persons:

```
1   Eliza    Ablovatski     <p>Eliza Ablovatski joined ...
2   One      More           Biography: Some interesting facts...
```

Books

```
1   1   0       <p><em>Zwischen Pruth und ...
1   2   0       <p><em>Czernowitz ist gewen ...
2   3   2001    Book1
2   4   2002    Book2
```

Articles

```
1   1   0       <p>"The Central European ...
1   2   0       <p>"Between Red Army and White ...
1   3   0       <p>"The Girl with the Titus-head: ...
2   4   2001    Article1
```

#### But what you really want to achieve is the *one, big table*

This is only possible with dynamic SQL. Start as above and change the query to the following. It will first find the columnnames automatically and then use a `UNION ALL` to force all data into the same structure and finally there's a big, dynamic `PIVOT`:

Attention: I added a `PARTITION BY PersonID` to the CTEs related ROW_NUMBERs. This is to get IDs starting with `1`for each person

```
With MyPersonCTE AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS PersonID
          ,p.value('FirstName[1]','varchar(max)') AS FirstName
          ,p.value('LastName[1]','varchar(max)') AS LastName
          ,p.value('Biography[1]','varchar(max)') AS Biography
          ,p.value('Expertise[1]','varchar(max)') AS Expertise
          ,p.value('Image[1]','varchar(max)') AS Image
          ,p.value('Link[1]','varchar(max)') AS Link
          ,p.query('Books') AS BookNode
          ,p.query('Articles') AS ArticleNode
          --same for Papers, Artwork...
    FROM @x.nodes('/People/Person') AS A(p) 
)
,MyBooksCTE AS
(
    SELECT MyPersonCTE.*
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY PersonID ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS BookID
          ,x.value('Year[1]','int') AS BookYear
          ,x.value('Details[1]','varchar(max)') AS BookDetails
    FROM MyPersonCTE
    CROSS APPLY MyPersonCTE.BookNode.nodes('/Books/Book') A(x)  
)
,MyArticlesCTE AS
(
    SELECT MyPersonCTE.*
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY PersonID ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS ArticleID
          ,x.value('Year[1]','int') AS ArticleYear
          ,x.value('Details[1]','varchar(max)') AS ArticleDetails
    FROM MyPersonCTE
    CROSS APPLY MyPersonCTE.ArticleNode.nodes('/Articles/Article') A(x)  
)
--same for Papers, Artwork...
SELECT p.*
      ,b.BookID
      ,b.BookYear
      ,b.BookDetails
      ,a.ArticleID
      ,a.ArticleYear
      ,a.ArticleDetails  
INTO #tempAllData
FROM MyPersonCTE AS p
LEFT JOIN MyBooksCTE AS b ON p.PersonID=b.PersonID
LEFT JOIN MyArticlesCTE AS a ON p.PersonID=a.PersonID ;

--#tempAllData is now filled with all data, copied in all combination: much to much
--but DISTINCT is your friend
--in this case you'd use the PersonID as FK in all related tables

SELECT DISTINCT PersonID,FirstName,LastName,Biography,Expertise --other fields
INTO #tempPerson
FROM #tempAllData;

SELECT DISTINCT PersonID,BookID,BookYear,BookDetails
INTO #tempBooks
FROM #tempAllData;

SELECT DISTINCT PersonID,ArticleID,ArticleYear,ArticleDetails
INTO #tempArticles
FROM #tempAllData;

DECLARE @columnNames VARCHAR(MAX)=
 STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',Book_'+CAST(BookID AS VARCHAR(10)) FROM #tempBooks FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')
+(SELECT DISTINCT ',Article_'+CAST(ArticleID AS VARCHAR(10)) FROM #tempArticles FOR XML PATH(''));

DECLARE @cmd VARCHAR(MAX)=
'SELECT p.*
FROM
(
    SELECT p.*
          ,''Book_''+CAST(BookID AS VARCHAR(10)) AS ColumnName
          ,ISNULL(CAST(BookYear AS VARCHAR(4)),'''') + '' '' + BookDetails AS Data
    FROM #tempPerson AS p
    INNER JOIN #tempBooks AS b ON p.PersonID=b.PersonID
    UNION ALL
    SELECT p.*
          ,''Article_''+CAST(ArticleID AS VARCHAR(10)) AS ColumnName
          ,ISNULL(CAST(ArticleYear AS VARCHAR(4)),'''') + '' '' + ArticleDetails AS Data
    FROM #tempPerson AS p
    INNER JOIN #tempArticles AS a ON p.PersonID=a.PersonID
) AS tbl
PIVOT
(
    MAX(Data) FOR ColumnName IN(' +  @columnNames + ')
) AS p;'


EXEC(@cmd);

DROP TABLE #tempArticles
DROP TABLE #tempBooks 
DROP TABLE #tempPerson
DROP TABLE #tempAllData;
```

Comment: This all works well once it's in the system, bu we are missing a key part outlined in the original question: How do I actually create the table and store all this information there? All this does is select the data and put it into a temporary table held in memory, I think.

Comment: When I run the query, all the data is shown in a table format, but when I select the top 1000 rows of the table in the database, it shows an empty database.

Comment: @jackskis Which table is this you are talking about?  My code is sample/test code working against temporary tables (defined by the leading `#`). It's easy to work against "real" tables. Is this something you are doing over and over or ist this a one time action?

Comment: Problem solved! I just added a `SELECT * into permenantTable
 FROM #tempAllData;` before dropping the temp table.