# Illegal XML Characters When Declaring XML Variable In SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, illegal-characters

**The Problem**

I am attempting to declare an XML variable and and set it equal to [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-JRzH4vekR5YUVHSDZtSHJjNHc/view?usp=sharing) XML file within my SQL query like this: `DECLARE @x XML = 'xml content here';`.
However, when I try to do this with my current XML file, I get this error message printed to my screen:

`Msg 9420, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
XML parsing: line 1132, character 265, illegal xml character`

**Ways I've Already Tried To Solve It**

- I've tried to escape the single quotes by replacing all the single quotes in the XML file with two single quotes and then copying into the query. No luck.
- I've tried taking out the ampersands, but that doesn't seem to work. Near where the error is detected by SQL, there don't seem to be any special characters. No luck again.

**The Question**

It seems to me that single quotes aren't the problem. I am having trouble finding exactly what the illegal character is, how I filter these characters out. Maybe importing the XML file from an external file and setting the contents equal to the variable instead of heard coding it will solve the issue. How would this work? I am also aware that single quotes have to be replaced by two single quotes. I did that, but I still have the exact same problem. Any help understanding the issue is appreciated.

**System Parameters**

- MS SQL Server Management Studio
- Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard

**The Full Code**

Here's the full code that I'm executing that's giving me the error:

```
DECLARE @x XML = ' copy xml file here... ';

With MyPersonCTE AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS PersonID
          ,p.value('FirstName[1]','varchar(max)') AS FirstName
          ,p.value('LastName[1]','varchar(max)') AS LastName
          ,p.value('Biography[1]','varchar(max)') AS Biography
          ,p.value('Expertise[1]','varchar(max)') AS Expertise
          ,p.value('Image[1]','varchar(max)') AS Image
          ,p.value('Link[1]','varchar(max)') AS Link
          ,p.query('Books') AS BookNode
          ,p.query('Articles') AS ArticleNode
          --same for Papers, Artwork...
    FROM @x.nodes('/People/Person') AS A(p) 
)
,MyBooksCTE AS
(
    SELECT MyPersonCTE.*
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS BookID
          ,x.value('Year[1]','int') AS BookYear
          ,x.value('Details[1]','varchar(max)') AS BookDetails
    FROM MyPersonCTE
    CROSS APPLY MyPersonCTE.BookNode.nodes('/Books/Book') A(x)  
)
,MyArticlesCTE AS
(
    SELECT MyPersonCTE.*
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS ArticleID
          ,x.value('Year[1]','int') AS ArticleYear
          ,x.value('Details[1]','varchar(max)') AS ArticleDetails
    FROM MyPersonCTE
    CROSS APPLY MyPersonCTE.ArticleNode.nodes('/Articles/Article') A(x)  
)
--same for Papers, Artwork...
SELECT p.*
      ,b.BookID
      ,b.BookYear
      ,b.BookDetails
      ,a.ArticleID
      ,a.ArticleYear
      ,a.ArticleDetails  
INTO #tempAllData
FROM MyPersonCTE AS p
LEFT JOIN MyBooksCTE AS b ON p.PersonID=b.PersonID
LEFT JOIN MyArticlesCTE AS a ON p.PersonID=a.PersonID ;

--#tempAllData is now filled with all data, copied in all combination: much to much
--but DISTINCT is your friend
--in this case you'd use the PersonID as FK in all related tables

SELECT DISTINCT PersonID,FirstName,LastName,Biography,Expertise --other fields
FROM #tempAllData;

SELECT DISTINCT PersonID,BookID,BookYear,BookDetails
FROM #tempAllData;

SELECT DISTINCT PersonID,ArticleID,ArticleYear,ArticleDetails
FROM #tempAllData;

DROP TABLE #tempAllData;
```

Comment: I just changed my link to allow for public viewing and added the code that I'm running that's giving me the error.

Comment: You're pasting text into a hardcoded variable declaration? It's probably a copy/paste error, or an unescaped single quote.

Comment: Create a **[mcve]** ***in the body of your question.***

Comment: I do escape all the single quotes, and still get this error. How would I solve this problem by importing the XML file some other way?

Comment: Apologies for the ambiguity. I edited the question in an attempt to make myself more clear. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried running it through [XmlValidation](http://www.xmlvalidation.com/)?

Comment: Yes. No problems detected.

Comment: You've still not created a [mcve].   **Voting to close...**

Comment: Do you have any specific suggestions that could improve my questions in the future? I have already read through that link you keep posting.

Comment: @jackskis The problem is likely in the `@x` variable value which, ironically, is currently stripped out from *the full code* section... so the suggestion would be, try to run just that part of your code. If it is enough to produce the error then the only part you need to post here is that line (also simplify your XML if it is too long, just make sure the simplified version still triggers the error)

Comment: @jackskis: Yes, in the future, and currently, your question should stand on its own, without reliance on offsite links which may become unavailable in the future.  Furthermore, you should eliminate all code and data except for the minimal needed to exhibit the error.  It's harder than dumping everything on your readers, but the exercise will benefit both you and your readers.

Comment: Hi @jackskis, I'm curious... Didn't my answer help you? I'd really like to help you through as the code you've posted is mine from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36390345/5089204) and I feel somehow responsible to get it work... :-)

Comment: Hey @Shnugo, I don't know if this is the right place to say this, but this is a project that runs on a server I only have access to Tuesdays and Fridays. I will try it out tomorrow afternoon and get back to you! Thank you very much for your help! It's been essential.

Comment: Yes.  It's working now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look, this is a reduced example to reproduce the error

In this snippet you've got twice the name "O’Brien" where the ’ makes troubles
And here “Experiencing physical warmth promotes interpersonal warmth” the opening and closing qoutes are problematic

```
DECLARE @x XML=
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<People>
<Person>
    <FirstName>Katherine</FirstName>
    <LastName>Corker</LastName>
    <Articles>
                <Article>
            <Year></Year>
            <Details><![CDATA[<p>Corker, K. S., Lynott, D., Wortman, J., Connell, L., Donnellan, M. B., Lucas, R. E., & O’Brien, K. (2014). High quality direct replications matter: Response to Williams (2014). Social Psychology, 45, 324-326. Available <a href="https://www.academia.edu/attachments/35015451/download_file?st=MTQxMzMwNDE0MiwxMzguMjguOS4xNjEsMjEzMTg%3D&s=work_strip">here.</a></p>
<p>Lynott, D., Corker, K. S., Wortman, J., Connell, L., Donnellan, M. B., Lucas, R. E., & O’Brien, K. (2014). Replication of “Experiencing physical warmth promotes interpersonal warmth” by Williams & Bargh (2008, Science). Social Psychology, 45, 216-222. Available <a href="https://www.academia.edu/attachments/33247494/download_file?st=MTQxMzMwNDE0MiwxMzguMjguOS4xNjEsMjEzMTg%3D&s=work_strip">here.</a></p>]]></Details>
        </Article>
            </Articles>
</Person>
</People>';
SELECT @x;
```

And now just change this

```
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

to this (don't forget the "N" in the beginning to force this to Unicode)

```
N'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
```

#### But just try this:

```
DECLARE @yourXML AS XML=
(
SELECT CONVERT(XML, BulkColumn,2) AS BulkColumn
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'X:\Path2file\faculty-xml.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS x
);
SELECT @yourXML;
```

With this you do not have to bother about encondings, you just read the file from a location on the disk...

Comment: If you want to look deeper into this, you might read this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/36402353/5089204